# php - return variable from function

Tags: php, function

I am trying to return a variable from a function. I have the function below, which inserts a postid to the database. I need the postid's value returned to another page.

**forum.php - Where the function is.**

```
function newTopic(){
    // Get the POST data
    global $ir;

    $postid = mysql_insert_id();

    mysql_query("UPDATE forum_topics SET post_id='$postid' WHERE topic_id='$topicid'");

    // No error found and the update was succesful - Return success!            
    return 100;
    return $postid;
}
```

**newtopic.php - Where I need the `$postid` variable.**

```
if($_POST)
{     
    $newTopic = $forum->newTopic();    

        /*
         * Return codes:
         * 100: Success
         */       
    switch($newTopic)
    {
        //If no error = success.    
        case 100:
            $success = 'You have successfully created the topic.';
            $issuccess = 1;
            $stop = true;
        break;
    }

    $checkerror = $error; 
    $checksuccess = $success;

} 

if($checksuccess){ 
    $contents.="
    ".alert("success","$success")."";
    refresh("3","/forum/t$id-$postid");
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to use $postid variable from the function newTopic(). Although, the $postid variable is empty.

How can I get the value from the function newTopic.php located in forum.php, to newtopic.php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have used

```
return 100;
```

your code will never see

```
return $postid;
```

You can use this code to return

```
return array("code"=>"100","postid"=>$postid);
```

Now in new_topic.php use the code as shown

```
if($_POST)
{

    $newTopic = $forum->newTopic();


        /*
         * Return codes:
         * 100: Success
         */

    switch($newTopic['code'])
    {

            //If no error = success.    
            case 100:
                $success = 'You have successfully created the topic.';
                $issuccess = 1;
                $stop = true;
            break;
    }

    $checkerror = $error; 
    $checksuccess = $success;

} 

        if($checksuccess){ 
        $contents.="
        ".alert("success","$success")."";
        refresh("3","/forum/t$id-$newTopic['postid']");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks that is returning value 100 before returning $postid variable.
That's wrong.Your code will exit the function at first return.

comment the line  **"//return 100;"**

OR return an array. You cannot return two values like u do.
Instead of doing

```
 return 100;
 return $postid;
```

Do

```
 //return 100;
 return array("successs"=>100,"id"=>$postid);
```

Then use your $newTopic variable as folows:
In switch:

```
switch($newTopic['success'])
```

Use the postId anywhere else

```
$newTopic['id']
```

Answer (score 1):

try with reference like in the below code

```
function newTopic(&$postid){
    // Get the POST data
    global $ir;

    $postid = mysql_insert_id();

    mysql_query("UPDATE forum_topics SET post_id='$postid' WHERE topic_id='$topicid'");

    // No error found and the update was succesful - Return success!            
    return 100;
}

....... //some codes
$postid = null;
newTopic($postid);
$my_postId = $postid; //Now you have your post ID
```

OR in you exists code like

```
if($_POST)
{ 
    $last_postid = null;    
    $newTopic = $forum->newTopic($last_postid );    

        /*
         * Return codes:
         * 100: Success
         */       
    switch($newTopic)
    {
        //If no error = success.    
        case 100:
            $success = 'You have successfully created the topic.';
            $issuccess = 1;
            $stop = true;
            $postid = $last_postid;
        break;
    }

    $checkerror = $error; 
    $checksuccess = $success;

} 

if($checksuccess){ 
    $contents.="
    ".alert("success","$success")."";
    refresh("3","/forum/t$id-$postid");
}
```

EDIT: Call-time pass-by-reference fixed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return two values you can not just write two returns.

There are several options to return more values. One is using an array:

```
return array(100, $postId);
```

and

```
list($status, $postId) = $forum->newTopic();
```

You can also use an associatve array as s.d suggested.

However, as your one variable only contains the status you can also use exceptions in the case the operation fails.